# How to solve this Trial Balance?

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I tried to solve [Tried Balance](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/moodysanalyticswomeninengineering/challenges/trail-balance/problem) question of Hackerrank by making a recursion but could not reach the correct solution.

I think it's a Knapsack problem which can only be solved by DP. How can I find out the correct solution or approach?

Comment: The one i can think of is similar to knapsack, as you thought. In this algo, for every element you decide if you want to keep it same array or change it to other one(we store both results), where keeping in same array doesnt change difference and no of steps, so no change is done and changing to other results in increment and decrement of diff and in increase in number of steps, so , dp[new_diff] = dp[old_diff] + 1. Note - You need to be careful of negative values of difference, better use map or some other data structure

Comment: Can you please provide relevant code to understand more?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/moodysanalyticswomeninengineering/challenges/trail-balance/forum   you can find a cpp solution in this link